# How to check if a javascript object has a certain property

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Suppose I have a javascript object like this:

```
window.config
config.UI = {
        "opacity": {
            "_type": "float",
            "_tag": "input",
            "_value": "1",
            "_aka": "opacity",
            "_isShow":"1"
 }
```

How can I judge if the "opacity" object has a property named "_test"?
like

```
var c=config.ui.opacity;
for(var i in c)
{
   //c[i]=="_test"?
}
```

How do I find out if it's assigned as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are at least three ways to do this; which one you use is largely up to you and sometimes even a matter of style, though there are some substantive differences:

#### `if..in`

You can use `if..in`:

```
if ("_test" in config.UI.opacity)
```

...because when used in a test (as opposed to the special `for..in` loop), `in` tests to see if the object or its prototype (or its prototype's prototype, etc.) has a property by that name.

#### `hasOwnProperty`

If you want to exclude properties from prototypes (it doesn't much matter in your example), you can use `hasOwnProperty`, which is a function all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`:

```
if (config.UI.opacity.hasOwnProperty("_test"))
```

#### Just retrieve it and check the result

Finally, you can just retrieve the property (even if it doesn't exist) and the decide what to do with the result by looking at the result; if you ask an object for the value of a property it doesn't have, you'll get back `undefined`:

```
var c = config.UI.opacity._test;
if (c) {
    // It's there and has a value other than undefined, "", 0, false, or null
}
```

or

```
var c = config.UI.opacity._test;
if (typeof c !== "undefined") {
    // It's there and has a value other than undefined
}
```

---

#### Being defensive

If it's possible that `config.UI` won't have an `opacity` property at all, you can make all of those more defensive:

```
// The if..in version:
if (config.UI.opacity && "_test" in config.UI.opacity)

// The hasOwnProperty version
if (config.UI.opacity && config.UI.opacity.hasOwnProperty("_test"))

// The "just get it and then deal with the result" version:
var c = config.UI.opacity && config.UI.opacity._test;
if (c) { // Or if (typeof c !== "undefined") {
```

That last one works because the `&&` operator is particularly powerful in JavaScript compared with some other languages; it's the corollary of the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).

Comment: There's a gotcha with "just retrieving it" I just ran into: If you're digging deep into an object and one of the parent properties of the thing you're looking for is undefined, you'll get a TypeError, not 'undefined.'

Comment: @worc: See the examples under "**Being defensive**" at the end. That's exactly the situation that constructs like `var c = config.UI.opacity && config.UI.opacity._test;` are for.

Comment: it's not *exactly* the problem i ran into. in my specific case an object like {{config}} was initialized but {{UI}} was undefined. so checking the {{UI}} fields {{opacity}} and {{_test}} fields ends up throwing an error rather than returning as *undefined*.

Comment: @worc: So you just do what I showed above: `var opacity = config && config.UI && config.UI.opacity;`

Comment: yeah, i know. i was more pointing out the gotcha where an incomplete defense will throw errors rather than return undefined.